# Get pid of long running command executed via at

Tags: linux, scheduling, process-management, at

I would like to spawn a persistent `netcat` server. My command of choice is the following:

```
echo "bash -c \"while [ 1 ]; do nc -l -p 1111 >> check; done\"" | at now
```

I am wondering how I can get the PID of the process created by `at` so that I can easily put the server to sleep when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tad tricky because of quoting, note change from " to '

The following will work if you submit your `at` job via `at -f file`

```
at -f nc.on now
cat nc.on
bash -c 'while [ 1 ]; do echo $$ > /var/run/atnc.pid; nc -l -p 1111  >> check; done'
```

the file `/var/run/atnc.pid` will have the process id of the bash which is running nc

You can cat the file to get the bash process id and kill it, terminating nc. Then `rm /var/run/atnc.pid`  (optional).